Original process fails to terminate
I have a PowerShell "module" that is really just a script that is supposed to elevate any script that invokes it:
if (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
    $OGScript = (Get-PSCallStack)[1].ScriptName
    $Params = if ((Get-PSCallStack)[1].InvocationInfo.BoundParameters.Keys -ne '') {
        "-$((Get-PSCallStack)[1].InvocationInfo.BoundParameters.Keys)"
    } else {
        $null
    }
    $Cmd = "-Command Set-Location `"$(Split-Path $OGScript)`"; & `"$OGScript`" $Params"
    $ProcArgs = @{
        FilePath     = 'PowerShell.exe'
        Verb         = 'RunAs'
        ArgumentList = $Cmd
    }
    Start-Process @ProcArgs
    Exit
}

The caller script would just need to have & path\to\Switch-ToAdmin.ps1 somewhere at the beginning.
The problem is the caller script gets executed both in the newly created elevated window and the original non-elevated window.
I thought the Exit bit was supposed to take care of that, i.e. terminate the original process before it gets run, but it doesn't seem to do anything, based on my testing.

The Exit command terminates the Switch-ToAdmin.ps1 not the caller.
You can change Exit to Stop-Process $PID since the caller and the callee are executed in the same session. This is radical, because it closes the session.
A less radical solution will be to set an Exit Code in the callee and check the automatic variable $LASTEXITCODE if it is equal to that code. As an example:
# Switch-ToAdmin.ps1 (callee)

if ( ... ) {
  ...
  Exit 10
}

# Caller
& 'path\to\Switch-ToAdmin.ps1'
If ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 10) { Exit }
...
# Code of the caller


Indeed, as Fabrice SANGA's helpful answer implies, an exit statement inside a script file (*.ps1) exits only that script, not also its caller.
The solution is to use a function instead, inside of which exit does apply to the calling script.
Thus, if you package your self-elevating code as a function that you export from a module, and you place that module in either of the two directories for user modules listed in $env:PSModulePath, it will implicitly be available to *.ps1 files via module auto-loading.
This technique is demonstrated using a dynamic module (see New-Module) for brevity in this answer, which also shows how to pass the original arguments through to the elevated process.
